# My program won't return

Tags: java, algorithm, return, anagram

I'm programming an algorithm to check if two words are anagrams, but it won't return true even though it should be doing so. Can someone give me advice?

```
public class Anagramme {

    public boolean Anagramme(boolean resultat) {

        String s1 = "parisien", s2 = "aspirine";


        if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            char[] ch1 = s1.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(ch1);
            String r1 = new String(ch1);
            char[] ch2 = s2.toCharArray();
            Arrays.sort(ch2);
            String r2 = new String(ch2);

            if (r1.equals(r2)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Here both `s1` and `s2` are not contains same value..

Comment: I tried your code and it returns true. I think the problem might be something else

Comment: consider `return r1.equals(r2);` as a much more concise way to end your method...

Answer (score 2):

I have rewrote your code and deleted unnecessary parts, and it works good for me.

```
public boolean anagram() { // changed here
    String s1 = "parisien", s2 = "aspirine";

    if (s1.length() != s2.length()) {
        return false;
    } else {
        char[] ch1 = s1.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(ch1);
        String r1 = new String(ch1);
        char[] ch2 = s2.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(ch2);
        String r2 = new String(ch2);
        return r1.equals(r2); // changed here
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
boolean anagram = anagram();
System.out.println("anagram = " + anagram);
```

And the result:

```
anagram= true
```

You can try it could it helps you!

Comment: I've tried the code but it returns the message that the principle method is not being found and that i should rename it to "public static void main(String[] args)". I'm using Eclipse by the way

Comment: You could use the same name as the method name 'anagram'

Comment: You can try the same as I gave an example above

Comment: Yes I've tried your code, it seems simpler than mine is, but it still won't return neither true or false, just an error.

Comment: it works. I used a main method. Thank you for your help

Comment: You are so welcome. If it really solved your problem, then you can the answer.  Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Using .equals this way asks if the references are the same. It does not compare the content of each array. If you want to compare the content of each array, either loop through and compare each character or use Arrays.equals.

Comment: This is not correct. Calling the `equals` method on a `String` does compare the contents of the `String`s.

Comment: Ah. You are correct. I responded too quickly and thought he was comparing the arrays.

Comment: That said, at least I tried to solve the issue instead of just giving the kid working code. J/S.

Comment: Which is exactly what leads to a kid who doesn't even know he needs a main method being able to pass his Java class...